# Multivariable Second Partial Derivative Test

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Find the value of D(a,b) using the second partial test for

g(x,y) = e^(3x^2 − 6y^2 + 36y)

I found the critical point which is at (0,3) but i cant seem to be able to find the value for D(a,b).

The answer I got after multiple attempts is -72e^54 which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first partial derivatives are

$f_x=6x\cdot e^{3x^2-6y^2+36y}, f_y=(-12y+36)\cdot e^{3x^2-6y^2+36y}$

Now you have to apply the *product rule* to get $f_{xx}$ and $f_{yy}$.

$f_{xx}=6\cdot e^{3x^2-6y^2+36y}+6x\cdot 6x\cdot e^{3x^2-6y^2+36y}$

$f_{yy}=-12\cdot e^{3x^2-6y^2+36y}+(-12y+36)^2\cdot e^{3x^2-6y^2+36y}$

$f_{xy}=6x\cdot (-12y+36)\cdot e^{3x^2-6y^2+36y}$

$d=f_{xx}\cdot f_{xy}-f_{xy}^2$

Finally you have to insert the values of the critical point.

---

$f_{xy}(0,3)=0$.

The part $6x\cdot 6x\cdot e^{3x^2-6y^2+36y}$ of $f_{xx}$ is $0$ as well.

The rest I´ve calculated [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6%5Ccdot%20e%5E%7B3*0%5E2-6*3%5E2%2B36*3%7D*-12%5Ccdot%20e%5E%7B3*0%5E2-6*3%5E2%2B36*3%7D%2B(-12*3%2B36)%5E2%5Ccdot%20e%5E%7B3*0%5E2-6*3%5E2%2B36*3%7D). I get $D(0,3)=-72\cdot e^{108}$

Comment: I seem to be getting the same final answer...

Comment: Which final answer ?

Comment: -72e^54 as the answer

Comment: Give me 10 minutes to calculate my D(0,3).

Comment: Thank so much for your time i must have just gone wrong in my calculations, you were very helpful have a great night! :) @callculus